# Picker View Components

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a 3 component picker view that works well. However I would like a feature when a user chooses option 1 out of the first component, the 2nd component shows certain data. BUT if the user chooses option 2 out of the first component, the 2nd component shows DIFFERENT data.

Basically in my code id like this to happen:

choosing "green" in component 1 shows otherseasonArray data in component 2

choosing "black" in component1 shows choiceArray data in component2

if that makes sense?

this is what I have so far .h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface view : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker2;

@end
```

and .m

```
#import "view2.h"

@interface view ()
{
NSArray*othercolourArray;
NSArray*otherseasonArray;
NSArray*otherotherArray;


NSArray*choiceArray;

}


@end

@implementation view

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


othercolourArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"green", @"black", nil];
otherseasonArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"summer", @"winter", nil];
otherotherArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"triangle", @"circle", nil];

choiceArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"choice1", @"choice2", nil];


}
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 3;


}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
switch (component) {
    case 0:
        return othercolourArray.count;
        break;


    case 1:
        return otherseasonArray.count;
        break;

    case 2:
        return otherotherArray.count;
        break;



    default:
        break;
}


return 0;
}



-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {



switch (component) {
    case 0:
        return [othercolourArray objectAtIndex:row];
        break;


    case 1:
        return [otherseasonArray objectAtIndex:row];
        break;


    case 2:
        return [otherotherArray objectAtIndex:row];
        break;





    default:
        break;
}


return 0;



}





- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

i have edited your code according to your requirements. You can use this as it is..
    If i have got your point, you will see this behaviour:
    choosing "green" in component 1, Will show you otherseasonArray data in component 2

```
choosing "black" in component1, Will show you  choiceArray data in component2
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSArray*othercolourArray;
    NSArray*otherseasonArray;
    NSArray*otherotherArray;


    NSArray*choiceArray;
    NSInteger selectedOptionFromColumn1;


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    othercolourArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"green", @"black",@"testColumn11" ,nil];
    otherseasonArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"summer", @"winter",@"testColumn22", nil];
    otherotherArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"triangle", @"circle",@"testColumn33", nil];

    choiceArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"choice11", @"choice22",@"choice34", nil];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 3;


}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0) {
            selectedOptionFromColumn1=[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];

            [pickerView reloadComponent:1];

    }
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            return othercolourArray.count;
            break;
         case 1:
            if (selectedOptionFromColumn1 == 0) {
                return otherseasonArray.count;
            }
            else if (selectedOptionFromColumn1 == 1){
                return choiceArray.count;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            return otherotherArray.count;
            break;



        default:
            break;
    }


    return 0;
}



-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {



    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            return [othercolourArray objectAtIndex:row];
            break;


        case 1:
            if (selectedOptionFromColumn1 == 0) {
                return [otherseasonArray objectAtIndex:row];
            }
            else if (selectedOptionFromColumn1 == 1)
            {
                 return [choiceArray objectAtIndex:row];
            }
            break;
          case 2:
            return [otherotherArray objectAtIndex:row];
            break;


         default:
            break;
    }


    return 0;



}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Let me know, if this meets your requirements ? you can also customise this according to your further requirements.

Comment: @Pammuel .. your welcome!!. I am glad that your purpose solved. You should upvote the answer as it will help others also.